# Count total numeric characters in a string

Tags: swift, string

I am trying to count the numbers inside a string input in a textfield, here's my code

```
var num = 0
.
. 
.

let stringArray = password.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted)
for item in stringArray {
    if let number = Int(item) {
        print("number: \(number)")
        num += 1
    }
}

if num > 4 {
    print("You Shall Pass!!")
}
else {
    print("You Shall Not Pass!!")
}
```

But when i print the num, it stays on 1. No matter how many number I input in the textfield, it will always print 1 and "you shall not pass!!"

Comment: what does your input look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an easier way. Change this line,

```
let stringArray = password.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted)
```

to,

```
let stringArray = password.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits)
```

Now the number of digits is one less than the number of elements in `stringArray`. So you could just use that.

```
if (stringArray.count - 1) > 4 {
    print("You Shall Pass!!")
} else {
     print("You Shall Not Pass!!")
}
```

Comment: Thanks, its working, but i wonder why is the digits is less than the number of elements in the array?

Comment: @Nodoodle Print the `stringArray` with an example. You'll understand it better when you actually see it ;)

Answer (score 3):

In more swifty approach, you may use `filter` on `password string` to identify frequency of numbers in it, like:

```
var password = "tHis4is5test8,#pass11" // 45811 - 5 numeric characters
let numsFrequency = password.filter {"0"..."9" ~= $0}.count
print(numsFrequency) // 5
```

**OR**

you may add this in an `Extension` to `String` and use it easily.

```
extension String {
    var numbersFrequency: Int {
        return String(self.filter { "0"..."9" ~= $0 }).count
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
print("1, 2, and 3".numbersFrequency) // 3
print("tHis4is5test8,#pass11".numbersFrequency) //5

let newPassword = "tHis4is5test8,#pass11"
print(newPassword.numbersFrequency) //5
```

Answer (score 1):

A different approach:

Remove all non-digit characters with Regular Expression and count the result.

```
let numberOfDigits = password.replacingOccurrences(of: "[^0-9]", with: "", options: .regularExpression).count
```